# select NULL as value with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, null

I have searched and have not found an answer to this question.

Please point me in the right direction if I missed it but how do I:

SELECT NULL as MyVariable in **PostgreSQL**. Any ideas?

Comment: on what purpose why you want null as an output ? please specify

Comment: @zdb What output are you after? which columns have NULL values, or that null values are ouput as "NULL"?

Comment: And what is the problem with this query `SELECT NULL AS MyVariable`? It works, but no one knows, what have you really expected?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `select null` will work fine in plain SQL. For a variable you need to use a stored function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. It does seem to work. It turns out in my code I was missing the AS part. I am moving a database from Oracle to PostgreSQL and only realized that "AS" was missing.

SELECT NULL MyVariable from DUAL
should have been 
SELECT NULL AS MyVariable